# Python, Tkinter, and OOP Struggles

Tags: python-3.x, class, tkinter

I am trying to create a GUI program using Tkinter and classes.  I am struggling to implement the functionality I need as I continuosly encounter roadblocks of passing variables between classes or functions in Tkinter.

- I have one class called GUI, which inherits from Tk to serve as the main window.
- I then have two separate classes, which inherit the Frame class from Tkinter
- These two frames house the various widgets that make up the program
- I then want to have a third Frame class that gets created conditionally and displays additional widgets based on one of the selection of one of the widgets within the previously mentioned classes inheriting from Tkinter Frames.

My problem is that I don't know how to properly implement this or if my train of thought is completely flawed.

Here's my main GUI class described:

```
class GUI(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Cert Generator")
        self.minsize(600, 600)
        self.config(padx=20, pady=20)

        # Creation of Upper Frame
        self.upper_frame = UpperFrame(self)

        # Creation of Lower Frame
        self.lower_frame = LowerFrame(self)

        self.mainloop()
```

We are focused on the second frame: LowerFrame.

```
class LowerFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=20)
        # LowerFrame Widgets
        self.instructions = Label(self, text="Select which coverages should appear on the cert:")
        self.instructions.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

        self.auto_StringVar = StringVar()
        self.add_auto = Label(self, text="Add Auto to the Cert?")
        self.add_auto.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.auto_check = ttk.Combobox(self)
        self.auto_check.grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.auto_check['values'] = ["Yes", "No"]
        self.auto_check.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lambda event:self.on_auto_combobox_change())

    def on_auto_combobox_change(self):
        """ Callback function to handle Combobox value changes """
        value = self.auto_check.get()
        self.auto_StringVar.set(value)
        if value == "Yes":
            pass
            # Do something to create the AutoCovFrame and accompanying widgets
```

Here is where my main problem is at.  I would like to create an instance of the AutoCovFrame class if the auto_check combobox within the lowerframe changes to "Yes".  Here is what that class looks like:

```
class AutoCoverageFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.grid(row=2, column=0)

        self.any_auto_StringVar = StringVar(value="No")
        self.any_auto = Checkbutton(self, text='Any Auto', variable=self.any_auto_StringVar, onvalue="Yes", offvalue="No")
        self.any_auto.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.owned_autos_StringVar = StringVar(value="No")
        self.owned_autos_only = Checkbutton(self, text='Owned Autos Only', variable=self.owned_autos_StringVar, onvalue="Yes", offvalue="No")
        self.owned_autos_only.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.hired_autos_only_StringVar = StringVar(value="No")
        self.hired_autos_only = Checkbutton(self, text='Hired Autos Only', variable=self.hired_autos_only_StringVar,onvalue="Yes", offvalue="No")
        self.hired_autos_only.grid(row=2, column=0)

        self.scheduled_autos_StringVar = StringVar(value="No")
        self.scheduled_autos = Checkbutton(self, text='Scheduled Autos', variable=self.scheduled_autos_StringVar, onvalue="Yes", offvalue="No")
        self.scheduled_autos.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.non_owned_autos_StringVar = StringVar(value="No")
        self.non_owned_autos = Checkbutton(self, text='Non-Owned Autos Only', variable=self.non_owned_autos_StringVar, onvalue="Yes", offvalue="No")
        self.non_owned_autos.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.remove_frame_button = Button(self, command=lambda: self.remove_frame(self, self.auto_StringVar),text="X")
        self.remove_frame_button.grid(row=1, column=2)
```

I think the problems here will be quite obvious for most as I am an extreme novice when it comes to coding.  But I think I will list out my questions directly:

1. Is there an easier or better way to create this other frame conditionally or am I left creating the frame within the on_combobox_check function?
2. After getting this frame created, similarly there are going to be values I need to grab and use later in this program.  How can I setup the code in a way to be able to grab those values later when needed?  I plan to have another function that grabs those values.

Comment: Why don't you create AutoCoverageFrame as a [modal dialog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window)?

Answer (score 0):

A fairly easy solution is to call `AutoCoverageFrame` ONCE as `self.AutoCovFrame` but do not apply grid manager.
Then when you select 'yes' in `Combobox` just use `self.AutoCovFrame.grid(...` to access it.
When you are finished with it press 'x' button to apply `grid_forget`.

Here are the main points.

```py
class LowerFrame(Frame):
    ...
        # Define AutoCovFrame once

        self.AutoCovFrame = AutoCoverageFrame(self)

    def on_auto_combobox_change(self):
        ...

        if value == "Yes":
            self.sAutoCovFrame.grid(row=2, column=0)


class AutoCoverageFrame(Frame):
    ...
        # remove grid during initialisation
        # self.grid(row=2, column=0)

        # change command to self.grid_forget 
        self.remove_frame_button = Button(
            self, command= self.grid_forget, text="X")
        self.remove_frame_button.grid(row=1, column=2)
```